# Use Zeroclipboard.js with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Trying to get Zeroclipboard.js to work in a Meteor app following an example here: http://www.thewebflash.com/2014/10/copy-to-clipboard-cross-browser-using.html.

I have the latest ZeroClipboard.js and ZeroClipboard.swf in the Client folder.

Within my template I have:

```
<template name="listPage">
<!-- some other markups -->
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<button type="button" id="btn-copy1" class="btn-copy">Copy to Clipboard</button>
<span class="span-message"></span>
</template>
```

Pair with event:

```
Template.listPage.events({
'click .btn-copy': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var client = new ZeroClipboard($('.btn-copy'));

    client.on('ready', function(event) {
        client.on('copy', function(event) {
            // `this` === `client`
            // `event.target` === the element that was clicked

            // Get the text content of <input> or <textarea> that comes immediately before the clicked button
            var $prevEle = $(event.target).prev();
            var text = $prevEle.is('textarea') ? $prevEle.val().replace(/\n/g, '\r\n') : $prevEle.val();

            // If value of `text` is not empty, set the data to clipboard
            if (text) {
                event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
            }
        });

        client.on('aftercopy', function(event) {
            // Check if copied text is not empty
            if (event.data["text/plain"]) {
                // Call something on successful copying
                $(event.target).next().stop().css('opacity', 1).text('Copied!').fadeIn(30).fadeOut(1000);
            }
        });
    });

    client.on('error', function(event) {
        ZeroClipboard.destroy();
    });
  }
});
```

I've also tried the simple example on https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Due to browser and Flash security restrictions, this clipboard injection can ONLY occur when the user clicks on the invisible Flash movie. A simulated click event from JavaScript will not suffice as this would enable clipboard poisoning.

Comment: msg on github, have you done this, patch is given there

Comment: So I may not be clicking on the invisible flash movie and therefore not copying anything.

Answer (score 1):

probably you have put zeroclipboard.swf in wrong place.

inspect in browser "copy button". if `new ZeroClipboard($('.btn-copy'))` worked ok - you ll see something like this.

```
<object id="global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge" 
name="global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="http://localhost:3000/client/lib/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1432275841705" 
height="100%" width="100%">.........</object>
```

note path to ZeroClipboard.swf. in my case it is /client/lib/ZeroClipboard.swf - that is, i've put ZeroClipboard.min.js to /client/lib - and it tries to search swf at same path.

this means you have to put .swf into /public folder of your meteor project, and create subfolders there that match that path. i believe there is an option when creating new ZeroClipboard instance to set this path explicitly - but .swf has to reside in /public folder. while it is in /client folder - it s not available.

also, are you sure it will work with class selector (`new ZeroClipboard($('.btn-copy'))`)? id selector (`#`) returns single item, class selector returns an array..

Comment: use ZeroClipboard.config({swfPath: '/path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf'}) to set path explicitly. reason to do so: default path is: ZeroClipboard.swf _in same folder where ZeroClipboard.js_ located. this means, it will try to use different paths on development (will be /client/.. - where you placed .js file on development, and / in production)

Comment: and one more note - constructor does not accept jquery element ($("#something")), instead it accepts DOM element (document.getElementById("something"))